# How to debug this issue? Initial load times for new URLs are extremely long in Windows, but not other OSes and machines

Tags: windows-11, internet-connection

When loading a new URL, it takes about 20 seconds to establish a connection, after which everything loads "as normal".

So for example if I go to `www.youtube.com`, it will take 20s+ (normal load time), and then every successive page I visit on youtube loads at normal speed. Then, if I want to go to `google.com`, it will take 20s+ (normal load time) to load.

This happens regardless if I clear my cache and cookies. It also happens across Chrome and FF browsers. I am currently dual booting two OSes (Windows 11 and Pop!_OS).

This is happening in Windows 11. When I try and access any site on Pop!_OS, it loads fast and as normal.

What I have tried:

- Clearing cache, clearing cookies.
- Resetting firewall settings.
- Checking DNS settings (currently set as automatic).

Comment: Perhaps try running [nslookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/nslookup) multiple times after booting Windows 11 and see if takes ~20 seconds on the first attempt to resolve a host name and then is faster on subsequent attempts. While the referenced Microsoft documentation page is for Microsoft server, checked on a Windows 11 Home 23H2 build that ``nslookup`` is installed.

Comment: `nslookup` actually made me realize the problem... it revealed I was running tailscale in the background (https://tailscale.com/) and this actually was the culprit!!!!! Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Please add an answer with the solution and come back later to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The tool I was looking for as [@Chester Gillon suggested in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1836464/how-to-debug-this-issue-initial-load-times-for-new-urls-are-extremely-long-in-w#comment2899871_1836464) was `nslookup`.

In PowerShell I called `nslookup` and discovered I was actually running [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/) in the background as an intermediary MagicDNS. After deactivating Tailscale, my load times returned to normal.

The troubleshooting steps I took with this problem was thus:

1. Clearing cache, clearing cookies.
2. Resetting firewall settings.
3. Checking DNS settings in Settings GUI.
4. `nslookup`.